# how to work with string literals mistakes in a compiler

Tags: java

I am working on a lexical analyzer, which is the first step to build a compiler. Given a .txt file, the code has to identify each one of the lexical components, for example if i have

```
String c = "abcdefg";
```

it has to print

```
String -> type
c -> variable
= -> assignment operator
"abcdefg" -> constant String
; -> Delimit
```

but if i have something like this:

```
String c = "abc
   d"; System.out.println("*");
```

the compile will say: String literal is not properly closed by a double quote. But how does the java compiler has to work with the other statement, the System.out.println("*"); does it have to ignore it, or it has to identify its elements?

Comment: The parser engages in error recovery, which consists of discarding tokens until a possible parse state has been re-established.

Comment: ... and popping parse states.

Answer (score 2):

The Nub of your question is this:

> But how does the java compiler has to work with the other statement, the System.out.println("*"); does it have to ignore it, or it has to identify its elements?

First of all, try it out and see what error messages the Java compiler actually gives you in an example like that.  (Obviously, you need to tweak your test case to isolate the handling of that particular situation ...)

You will most likely find that the compiler *doesn't* do a perfect job of recovering.  I would expect that the strategy for dealing with strings that are not closed at the end of line would be to assume that the string literal is closed and continue "lexing" in non-quoted mode.  But in your example, that is liable to give further errors.

Which brings me to my second point.  I would advise you to not to try too hard with recovery from lexical errors.  Focus on getting the lexer / compiler to work in the cases where the input is valid.  You can always come back an improve on the error recovery later ... when you got more important things working properly.

(And @EJP's comment is spot on.  The "heavy duty" error recovery is typically done at the parser level, not the lexer level.)

Finally: your requirements:

> ```
> String c = "abcdefg";
> ```
>
> it has to print
>
> ```
> String -> type
> c -> variable
> = -> assignment operator
> "abcdefg" -> constant String
> ; -> Delimit
> ```

If you are parsing real Java, then a (pure) lexer cannot do that.  The problem is that it is not possible to determine that `String` is a type (or should be a type) and `a` is a variable name (or should be a variable name) in the lexer.  Indeed, if you ignore the grammatical context (which is typically not available to a lexer!) then `String` could be all sorts of things, including a class name, a package name, a method name, a field name, a local variable name and so on.

The normal way to handle that is for the lexical analyser to treat both `String` and `a` as "identifier"s ... and leave it for the parser and/or the semantic analyser to sort it out.